# How to a recover a text from a wrong encoding?

Tags: encoding, character-encoding

I have got some files created from some asian OS (chinese and japanese XPs)
the file name is garbled, for example:

> ÐÂ¸è+¾«Ñ¡Õä²ØºÏ¼­

how i can recover the original text?
I tried with this in c#

```
Encoding unicode = Encoding.Unicode;
Encoding cinese = Encoding.GetEncoding(936);
byte[] chineseBytes = chinese.GetBytes(garbledString);
byte[] unicodeBytes = Encoding.Convert(unicode, chinese, chineseBytes);
//(Then convert byte in string)
```

and tried to change unicode to windows-1252 but no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Encoding unicode = Encoding.Unicode;
```

That's not what you want. “Unicode” is Microsoft's totally misleading name for what is really the UTF-16LE encoding. UTF-16LE plays no part here, what you have is a simple case where a 936 string has been misdecoded as 1252.

Windows codepage 1252 is similar but not the same as ISO-8859-1. There is no way to tell which is in the example string as it does not contain any of the bytes 0x80-0x9F which are different in the two encodings, but I'm assuming 1252 because that's the standard codepage on a western Windows install.

```
Encoding latin= Encoding.getEncoding(1252);
Encoding chinese= Encoding.getEncoding(936);

chinese.getChars(latin.getBytes(s));
```

Answer (score 4):

It's a double-encoded text. The original is in Windows-936, then some application assumed the text is in ISO-8869-1 and encoded the result to UTF-8. Here is an example how to decode it in Python:

```
>>> print 'ÐÂ¸è+¾«Ñ¡Õä²ØºÏ¼­'.decode('utf8').encode('latin1').decode('cp936')
新歌+精选珍藏合辑
```

I'm sure you can do something similar in C#.

Comment: Suggest `u'ÐÂ¸è+¾«Ñ¡Õä²ØºÏ¼­'.encode('cp1252').decode('cp936')`: the UTF-8 was only coping with the pasted bytes. Either way this depends on the encoding of the terminal you paste the string into.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to `Encoding.Convert` is the *source* encoding, Shouldn't that be `chinese` in your case? So

```
Encoding.Convert(chinese, unicode, chineseBytes);
```

might actually work. Because, after all, you want to convert CP-936 *to* Unicode and not vice-versa. And I'd suggest you don't even try bothering with CP-1252 since your text there is *very* likely *not* Latin.

Comment: i tried both combinations before asking the question, and did not worked, so i was thinking the one i posted it was right, because the source encoding is not chinese, right?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I just ran into the same situation while trying to migrate WordPress upload files off of an old Windows Server 2008 R2 server. [bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1565059)'s answer set me on the right track, but I had to search for the right encoding/decoding pair.

With the following C#, I found the relevant encoding/deciding pair:

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // garbled
        string s = "2020ç«¹æ…¶æœ¬æ¨‚ä»æ³¢åˆ‡äºžæ´²æ³•ç­µ-Intro-2-1024x643.jpg";
        // expected
        string t = "2020竹慶本樂仁波切亞洲法筵-Intro-2-1024x643.jpg";

        foreach( EncodingInfo ei in Encoding.GetEncodings() )  {
            Encoding e = ei.GetEncoding();
            foreach( EncodingInfo ei2 in Encoding.GetEncodings() )  {
                Encoding e2 = ei2.GetEncoding();
                var s2 = e2.GetString(e.GetBytes(s));
                if (s2 == t) {
                    var x = ei.CodePage;
                    Console.WriteLine($"e1={ei.DisplayName} (CP {ei.CodePage}), e2={ei2.DisplayName} (CP {ei2.CodePage})");
                    Console.WriteLine(t);
                    Console.WriteLine(s2);
                }
            }
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine("-----------");
        Console.WriteLine(t);
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.GetEncoding(65001).GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(s)));
    }
}
```

It turned out that the correct encoding/deciding in my case was:

```
e1=Western European (Windows) (CP 1252), e2=Unicode (UTF-8) (CP 65001)
```

So the last line of code is a one-liner for the correct conversion `Console.WriteLine(Encoding.GetEncoding(65001).GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(s)));`.